# Python: how to choose only certain integers within brackets using regex

Tags: python, regex, integer

I am stuck while writing a function of searching integers in square brackets that should find from an input string all integers that are enclosed in brackets taking into account an additional restriction: there can be whitespace between the number and the brackets, but no other character besides those that make up the integer.

So far, I wrote the code below, but it doesn't work for the last test with +-43 which shouldn't be count as an integer. Could you help me to solve this issue?

Thanks!

```
import re

def integers_in_brackets(s):
    l = list(int(s) for s in re.findall(r'\[\s*\+?(-?\d+)\s*\]', s))
    print(l)
    return list(l)
```

Tests:

```
integers_in_brackets("  afd [asd] [12 ] [a34]  [ -43 ]tt [+12]xxx")
integers_in_brackets("afd [asd] [12 ] [a34]  [         -43 ]tt [+12]xxx!")
integers_in_brackets("afd [128+] [47 ] [a34]  [ +-43 ]tt [+12]xxx!")
```

Comment: `\[\s*([-+]?\d+)\s*]` ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/9qyAfi/1))?

Comment: `\[(?!\s*\+-)\s*\+?(-?\d+)\s*]` ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/9qyAfi/2))?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: Thank you, it works!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regular expression quite literally says optional plus followed by optional minus. If that's not what you want, perhaps you want *either* a plus or a minus?

```
r'\[\s*([-+]?\d+)\s*\]'
```

If you want either but not both, but capture a minus but not a plus, maybe add a lookahead to say "optional plus if not immediately followed by a minus":

```
r'\[\s*(?:\+(?!-))?(-?\d+)\s*\]'
```